# How to run ssh-agent and ssh-add through an SH script?

Tags: linux, bash, ssh

I have two following commands which I manually run when I connect on my VPS:

```
eval ssh-agent $SHELL
ssh-add /home/duvdevan/.ssh/id_rsa
```

I tried adding them into a `ssh.sh` and run it within that directory using:

```
./ssh.sh
```

But nothing happends.

I'm not that `bash`-savvy so any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Instead of running, you need to *source* the script:

```
. ./ssh.sh
```

Otherwise, the environment variables set by the `eval` command will not be visible in your current shell, and so it cannot know where to find the running ssh agent.

To give a bit more background, here's how this works:

- the `ssh-agent` command starts an ssh agent, and prints to stdout the environment variables you need to set to connect to the agent. The output is formatted as commands to execute. For a test, you can just run this command and see what it prints
- the `eval` command executes the commands printed by `ssh-agent`. As mentioned earlier, these are commands to set environment variables. After these are executed, the ssh commands you will run in this shell will know where to find the agent
- the `ssh-add` command is able to find the agent, thanks to the environment variables set earlier
- these variables are set until the script exits. When you run `./ssh.sh`, the variables are set inside the process of that script, and longer available after the script is finished
- by sourcing the `ssh.sh` script using `.`, the commands inside will be executed in the current shell, and therefore the environment variables are still set, and so your ssh related command can find the agent

Comment: do I need to add `#/sh/bash` to the top of my `.sh` script?

Comment: No, that has nothing to do with this